# How to check whether an Entity is related or not to another entity

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am new to Core Data

I have 2 Entities `Routine` and `Exercise` that are related as Routine.exercise and Exercise.routine.
User Routine has a name and so does user Exercise.

I tried
and also tried jsut `Routine.exercise = Exercise` but this gives me a warning saying  `Comparision of distinct pointer type (NSSET and Exercise)` and I also tried doing `Routine.exercise.name = @"theName"` but i was pushing it as i cant get the name of Exercise like that...

```
if (Routine.exercise == Exercise.routine) {
NSLOG(@"YES");
} else {
NSLOG(@"NO");
}
```

Basically I just want to know if Exercise has stablished a relationship or not with Routine. Could anyone help me with this query please?

is a Many to Many relationship

[image]

Comment: is A.userB a to-many relationship? If so that would explain the warning since those are stored as an NSSet.

Comment: is a Many to Many relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

Get the objects you want to test

```
Routine *testRoutine = ...;
Exercise *testExercise = ...;
```

Check if the exercise is contained in the set of objects in the relationship

```
if ([testRoutine.exercise containsObject:testExercise]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a many-to-many relationship, you cannot use `Routine.exercise = Exercise`, because the relationship is an NSMutableSet. Following is the correct way to add an object to the relationship:

```
NSMutableSet *rel = [routineObject mutableSetValueForKey:@"exercise"];
[rel addObject:exerciseObject];
```